# A place, some place, some places

Tags: grammar, questions, word-difference

A place refers to some place in general right? E.g "I went to a place that had lots of cars in there." What confuses is me the use of "some place" and "some places".  If I say "I took a photo of some place" meaning of some random unknown place but I don't remember its name. Is my sentence correct here

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly correct ! Using `a place` means you are telling about a place you *know*. 
 Using `some place` means you are telling about a place you might *not* know.

Comment: Okay thankyou that was helpful. I need to ask you one more question that is relevant to it, for instance , if i ask my friend "do you know some guy named Chris " or do you know any Chris" would that be okay too?

Comment: *do you know anyone named chris* would be a better option to use and moreover *do you know some guy named Chris* is correct. Also if you think my answer is satisfying, please tick it.

Comment: "Some place" is actually "someplace"